# Barplot by month - python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to do two bar plot (Descending order) in python with following criteria,

1- observations by month with total count.

2- observations by month with value A > 0.

I am struggling to create this in python.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you a can try this:

```
df.groupby('month', sort=False)['value A'].agg(['sum', 'count']).plot.bar()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thank you Scott. this works too. but i need to show the graph where count is > 0 (to group by month) and that's where actually i am struggling .

Comment: Is value A either one or zero?  Then count >0 would be sum.

Comment: in my observations, value A is not either zero or one.